# AsyncTask RecyclerView NullPointerException

Tags: android, android-asynctask, nullpointerexception, android-recyclerview

I'm getting a NullPointerException when I try to set data to my RecyclerView from an AsyncTask. I've tried many ways and I've searched all the web e read many Stackoverflow questions, but I still need a help. I'm new to Android.

Adapter:

```
    public class DrugstoreAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DrugstoreAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private static final String TAG = "DrugstoreAdapter";
    private List<Drugstore> drugstoreList;
    private Context context;

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private final TextView textView;

        public ViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            // Define click listener for the ViewHolder's View.
            v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Element " + getAdapterPosition() + " clicked.");
                }
            });
            textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        }

        public TextView getTextView() {
            return textView;
        }
    }

    public DrugstoreAdapter(Context context, List<Drugstore> drugstoreList){
        this.context = context;
        this.drugstoreList = drugstoreList;
    }

    // Create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
        // Create a new view.
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.text_row_item, viewGroup, false);

        return new ViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Element " + position + " set.");

        Drugstore drugstore = drugstoreList.get(position);
        holder.textView.setText(drugstore.getTitle());
    }

    // Return the size of your dataset (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return drugstoreList.size();
    }
}
```

Fragment:

```
    public class DrugstoreFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final String TAG = "RecyclerViewFragment";
    private static final String KEY_LAYOUT_MANAGER = "layoutManager";
    private static final int SPAN_COUNT = 2;
    private static final int DATASET_COUNT = 60;

    private enum LayoutManagerType {
        LINEAR_LAYOUT_MANAGER
    }

    protected LayoutManagerType mCurrentLayoutManagerType;

    RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    protected CustomAdapter mAdapter;
    protected RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    protected DrugstoreAdapter drugstoreAdapter;
    protected List<Drugstore> drugstoreList = new ArrayList<>();


    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //initDataset();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_drugstore, container, false);

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fg_recycler_view, container, false);
        rootView.setTag(TAG);

        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);

        // LinearLayoutManager is used here, this will layout the elements in a similar fashion
        // to the way ListView would layout elements. The RecyclerView.LayoutManager defines how
        // elements are laid out.
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        mCurrentLayoutManagerType = LayoutManagerType.LINEAR_LAYOUT_MANAGER;

        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

        /**
         * NEW
         */
        drugstoreAdapter = new DrugstoreAdapter(getActivity(), drugstoreList);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(drugstoreAdapter);

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        initDataset();
    }


    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Save currently selected layout manager.
        savedInstanceState.putSerializable(KEY_LAYOUT_MANAGER, mCurrentLayoutManagerType);
        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    }

    /**
     * Generates Strings for RecyclerView's adapter. This data would usually come
     * from a local content provider or remote server.
     */
    private void initDataset() {
        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
        String email = "";
        String type = "getDrugstores";
        email = preferences.getString("email", null);

        WorkInBackground wib = new WorkInBackground(getActivity());
        wib.execute(type, email);

        /*Drugstore drugstore = new Drugstore("F1");
        drugstoreList.add(drugstore);
        drugstore = new Drugstore("F2");
        drugstoreList.add(drugstore);
        drugstore = new Drugstore("F3");
        drugstoreList.add(drugstore);
        drugstore = new Drugstore("F4");
        drugstoreList.add(drugstore);
        drugstore = new Drugstore("F5");
        drugstoreList.add(drugstore);

        drugstoreAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();*/

    }
}
```

AsycTask:

```
    public class WorkInBackground extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_DRUGSTORE = "fornecedor";

    Helper helper = new Helper();
    SessionManager sessionManager;
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    Context context;
    Intent goToMain;
    private String type;
    private String email;
    private String ll;
    int success;

    private Drugstore drugstore = new Drugstore();
    List<Drugstore> drugstoreList;
    DrugstoreAdapter drugstoreAdapter;
    protected RecyclerView mRecyclerView;

    String ENCODING_UTF8 = "UTF-8";
    String ENCODING_ISO = "iso-8859-1";
    public static final int CONNECTION_TIMEOUT = 10000;
    public static final int READ_TIMEOUT = 15000;
    public static final String REQUEST_METHOD = "POST";

    public WorkInBackground(Context context){
        this.context = context;
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        sessionManager = new SessionManager(context);
        goToMain = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        //mRecyclerView.setAdapter(new DrugstoreAdapter(context, drugstoreList));
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        type = params[0];
if (type.equals("getDrugstores")) {
            email = params[1];

            try {
                URL url = new URL(helper.link + helper.url_drugstores);

                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setReadTimeout(READ_TIMEOUT);
                httpURLConnection.setConnectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod(REQUEST_METHOD);
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);

                /*OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, ENCODING_UTF8));

                String postData = URLEncoder.encode("email", ENCODING_UTF8)+"="+URLEncoder.encode(email, ENCODING_UTF8);

                bufferedWriter.write(postData);
                bufferedWriter.flush();
                bufferedWriter.close();
                outputStream.close();*/

                InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, ENCODING_ISO));

                String result = "";
                String line;

                //String[] array = new String[0];
                String[] myarray = new String[10];
                int x = 0;
                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    //result += line;
                    myarray[x] = line;
                    x++;
                }
                bufferedReader.close();
                inputStream.close();
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();
                Log.d("WHERE: ", "RESULT " + result);

                //JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(result);

                //JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_DRUGSTORE);
                //JSONArray jsonArray = result;

                //JSONArray json = new JSONArray(result);
                for (int i = 0; i < result.length(); i++) {

                    //JSONObject e = result.getChars(i);
                    String e = myarray[i];

                    Log.d("JSON: ", "" + e);

                    drugstore.setTitle(e);

                    drugstoreList = new ArrayList<>();
                    drugstoreList.add(drugstore);

                }

                //drugstoreAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                return result;

            } catch (ProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        progressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if (progressDialog.isShowing()) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
//mRecyclerView.setAdapter(drugstoreAdapter);
            //mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(new DrugstoreAdapter(this.context, drugstoreList));
            //drugstoreAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }


    }
```

Logcat:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.setAdapter(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter)' on a null object reference
                                                                    at br.unisinos.mobicine.classes.WorkInBackground.<init>(WorkInBackground.java:69)
                                                                    at br.unisinos.mobicine.fragments.DrugstoreFragment.initDataset(DrugstoreFragment.java:114)
                                                                    at br.unisinos.mobicine.fragments.DrugstoreFragment.onViewCreated(DrugstoreFragment.java:93)
                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1086)
                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1252)
                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:742)
                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1617)
                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:570)
                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
                                                                    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1177)
                                                                    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1025)
                                                                    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1545)
                                                                    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
                                                                    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
                                                                    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
                                                                    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748)
                                                                    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630)
                                                                    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
                                                                    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
                                                                    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
                                                                    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
                                                                    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:715)
                                                                    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:461)
                                                                    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
                                                                    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
                                                                    at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:668)
                                                                    at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:735)
                                                                    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
                                                                    at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:1075)
                                                                    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
                                                                    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
                                                                    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
                                                                    at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:135)
                                                                    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
                                                                    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
                                                                    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
                                                                    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748)
                                                                    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630)
                                                                    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
                                                                    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
                                                                    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
                                                                    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
                                                                    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
                                                                    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
                                                                    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748)
                                                                    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630)
                                                                    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
                                                                    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
                                                                    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
                                                                    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2643)
                                                                    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
                                                                    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2100)
                                                                    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1216)
                                                                    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1452
```

EDIT (New error):

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{br.unisinos.mobicine/br.unisinos.mobicine.activities.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setAdapter(android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter)' on a null object reference
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setAdapter(android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter)' on a null object reference
                                                                      at br.unisinos.mobicine.fragments.TabFragment.onCreateView(TabFragment.java:30)
                                                                      at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1974)
                                                                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
                                                                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1252)
                                                                      at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:742)
                                                                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1617)
                                                                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.execPendingActions(FragmentController.java:339)
                                                                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:601)
                                                                      at br.unisinos.mobicine.activities.MainActivity.onStart(MainActivity.java:77)
                                                                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1237)
                                                                      at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6253)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2379)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: Please post the full logcat of the error.

Comment: Here is the logcat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not instantiating the `mRecyclerView` anywhere in your `WorkInBackground` `AsyncTask` and you're declaring it like this:

```
protected RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
```

This means that you're declaring a new field in this class, which means you're not using the one which you instantiated in the Activity. You **do not need** to set adapter again here:

```
mRecyclerView.setAdapter(new DrugstoreAdapter(this.context, drugstoreList));
```

You've already done it in `onCreateView`. Just remove it from there and it should not crash. If you want to access the `mRecyclerView` from within the `AsyncTask`, simply pass it in the constructor (and maybe call `notifyDataSetChanged` if new data has been added.

Comment: Hm, not we have `NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setAdapter(android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter)' on a null object reference
                                                                      at br.unisinos.mobicine.fragments.TabFragment.onCreateView(TabFragment.java:30)` Which means that you might have not gotten the `id` right. Which line is line 30 in `TabFragment`?

Comment: viewPager.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(getChildFragmentManager()));

Comment: Offtopic: you said you are new to Android, so I decided to mention something that has helped me a lot with my app which is internet-dependent. Volley library by Google. Since I found it I don't use ASyncTasks anymore, in my opinion code looks much nicer and it also offers nice things like easy loading of images and even straight into ImageViews. Look into it after solving this.

Comment: @Alan I cannot see that line anywhere in your code. Regardless, I hope you fix this new error, but please consider accepting the answer if it helped you fix your **original** problem. Ask a new question if you can't solve it yourself.

Comment: You were right! It worked. For the second error, just a clean project did the trick. Thank you.

Comment: @iBobb I'll give it a try. Thank you for your suggestion.